# how to click a link in IE using excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, ie-automation

I am trying to wrote some code that will lookup a word in an excel cell, the search for that word and, most importantly, click on the link that returns.

I have the search part down, but it's the click on the link I'm struggling with.
the HMTL extract is -

```html
<span>
<div class="searchResult webResult ">
<div class="resultTitlePane">
<h3>
<a class="outbound" href="whatever" target ="" rel="nofollow" rev="lots of 
text">..</a>
</h3>
</div>
```

I've not typed out the href and rel text, but I just want to be able to click the link that's returned and follow through to that site.
Any help please?

this is my code -

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim RegEx As RegExp, RegMatch As MatchCollection
Dim MyStr As String
Dim pDisp As Object
Dim dtStartTime As Date
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Set RegEx = New RegExp
Dim iedoc As Object
SearchEng = "http://easysearch.org.uk/search/?s="

LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Do Until i = LastRow + 1
    SearchMe = Range("A" & i)
    ie.Navigate SearchEng & SearchMe
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    MyStr = ie.document.body.innerText
    Set RegMatch = RegEx.Execute(MyStr)        

    If RegMatch.Count > 0 Then
        ie.Navigate RegMatch(0)
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop

        ie.Visible = True        
        Set iedoc = ie.document
        ''NEED TO ADD SOMETHING HERE TO CLICK LINK''

    End If

    i = i + 1
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
Loop 
Set RegEx = Nothing
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not enough html code to provide you with an answer. In some cases, you can use the class names to help you get to your link, but since this is a search result, you will have many class names with the same name. Is any part of the `<a class...>` line unique to the search result?

Comment: I'll have a look, if it makes it easier, I only want to search the first result though.

Comment: That would probably make it easier. Can you post any code that you already have so I can see where you're stuck and build off that code?

Comment: Hi, anyone please able to help with this?

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can replace you placeholder: `''NEED TO ADD SOMETHING HERE TO CLICK LINK''` with:

```
iedoc.getElementsByClassName("resultTitlePane")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

---

In response to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963826/how-to-click-a-link-in-ie-using-excel-vba/49101338?noredirect=1#comment85284136_49101338) of readystate not completing:

You can continue to use your readystate loop, and then loop the actual object until it becomes available, then click it:

```
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

ie.Visible = True        
Set iedoc = ie.document

' ^ ^ ^ ^ Already part of your code

Dim myBtn As Object
Set myBtn = Nothing

' Loop object while it's Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Do While myBtn Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    set myBtn = iedoc.getElementsByClassName("resultTitlePane")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

myBtn.Click
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it doesn't look like it's working, it will cycle through all the keywords, but not actually follow through on the link

Comment: If I F8 through the code with a stop at this line it works, but not otherwise, does it need some kind of pause there?  I tried the code 
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: If your readystate doesn't work then you can loop the object till it becomes ready. I will update in a second

Comment: Hi, thanks, but again I have a problem, it runs once, (but doesn't seem to open the link) then when it gets to the second time around it's erroring at myBtn.Click

Comment: does it still work when you step through it manually? Can you add `Msgbox ieDoc is Nothing` right above the loop and tell me if it's true or false?

Comment: says FALSE both times

Comment: That's good. But does this still run when you F8 it line by line?

Comment: it will only do it once if I place a stop on that line, will still error second tine around

Comment: @SimonB Oh! I failed to see this was in a loop. We need to set the myBtn to Nothing. Update coming in a second

Comment: that seems to work when I step through, but not when running it properly, it still seems to miss the bit where it opens the linked page

Comment: Hi @KDavis any chance you could take another quick look at this please?